# Finding the probability for the sum of 2 variables

Tags: probability, statistics, uniform-distribution

I’ve been given the joint density function: f$_X$$_,$$_Y$(x,y)=C when (X,Y) is uniform over [-1,1]$^2$. I’ve been tasked with finding P{|2X+Y|$\le$1} and P{X=Y} however I’m stuck in my question, I’ve deduced already that C=1/4 in my working, however i’m not too sure how I can apply this to find the probability tasked.

Comment: You want to integrate the density over the area represented by the event $|2X+Y|\le 1$ (or the event $X=Y$).  You can then divide by the integrate the density over the whole area, but since with $C=\frac14$ this is $1$, it is not strictly necessary.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can understand much of this, what is 1? you can divide by the integrate the density over the whole area? This confused me more than it helped me.

Comment: Just use the first sentence as a suggestion, if the second is confusing - it was more of a comment.

Comment: @Henry okay thanks for the help.

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independent? You haven't given us enough information to work out $\mathbb{P}(X=Y)$.

Comment: No, @A.M.  The *joint density function* contains enough information on the dependency.

Comment: @wizardofloz  The probability that the random point $\langle X,Y\rangle$ is *in the square* is $1$, because that is the total probability.

Answer (score 3):

You have $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \frac{1}{4}$ for $(X,Y)\sim U([-1,1]\times [-1,1])$.

For both the probabilities you want to find you need to integrate twice in the area that you’re given. For the first one you need to integrate where $|2X-Y|\leq 1$ therefore you need to integrate in the area $$D=\bigg\{(x,y): \frac{-1-y}{2}\leq x \leq \frac{1-y}{2} \text{ and } y\in[-1,1]\bigg\}$$

So, integrate your $f_{X,Y}$ in that for $x$ between the above and for $y$ in $[-1,1]$.

For the second, I think an easily understandable approach is to find $\mathbb{P}[X=Y]=1-\mathbb{P}[X>Y]-\mathbb{P}[X<Y]$.

Answer (score 2):

You have a uniform distribution over a $2{\times}2$ square; specifically the $[-1,1]^2$ square.  Probabilities of events within this space can be measured graphically; just compare the areas covered by the events.

Plot the lines $2X+Y=1$ and $2X+Y=-1$ within the square, and it becomes trivial to determine the probability.

The event of $\{\lvert 2X+Y\rvert\leq 1\}$ is a quadrilateral (formed of two right triangles).

The complement, $\{\lvert 2X+Y\rvert>1\}$, is two right triangles.